# Cannot mount or erase or use first aid on a partition of WD hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition, mount

i wanted to use this partition for the Time Machine, i tried creating this partition on windows machine as it won't erase the data. using AOMEI app. it was later formated with FAT32. then i came to my macbook, time machine picked up that partition; so I clicked on it but it gave me error. (sorry for not giving a screenshot)

---

After googling i found some codes for mounting fat32 but that didn't work.

```
diskutil mount /dev/disk2s2
Volume on disk2s2 failed to mount
Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

now i am left with a partition which don't mount.
here are some screenshot after running diskutil commands
[image]

[image: b]

Comment: Since you mention you have access to a Windows PC. The DISKPART command line tool is often used to delete partitions that are marked un-deletable. I use it myself to "clean" a drive of various (mostly) boot partition put on drives by Windows. Have you thought of using that?

Comment: In the second screenshot, you're trying to erase the partition, not the entire disk. Can you click on the disk (should be a model number) that's directly above the first partition. Then, try erasing it.